# How can I write javascript enable or disable in php when page is idle

Tags: php, javascript

How do I detect if javascript is enabled or disabled in the browser when the page is idle?

Comment: ...and do what with this information? Send it to the server?

Comment: Not possible I am afraid. PHP is server-side, js is clientside

Comment: @OptimusCrime there is a not-100%-reliable method of doing this - you could set a cookie on the first page load of `javascriptEnabled = 0`, then have a JS that sets it to `1`. That way, if the value of the cookie is `1`, you know JS and cookies must be enabled in the client. Admittedly this method is not even slightly fool-proof, but it is probably as good as you will ever get... Indeed, it is *so* unreliable, I'm not even going to post it as an answer.

Comment: You are right @DaveRandom, that would work. But since it involes so much unrelaiability, it's best to find a way around this problem. Most, most, most people enable js anyways.

Comment: You need to determine whether your intended audience will need a fallback to JavaScript.  Today, most web pages simply break if the user has JS disabled.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: One word: NoScript. Many, many, many people only enable JS as needed. Also, not everything out on the Web is a full-featured desktop browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for "how to check if JS is disabled or enabled" - you could (ab)use the `noscript` element of HTML for this:

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://www.example.org/no-js" />
</noscript>
```

and if JS is enabled, well, you can report this via AJAX, or make a different redirect:

```
<script>
    window.location = 'http://www.example.org/js-is-enabled';
</script>
```

Note that

- this requires one extra redirection at page load
- some browsers might get confused by the combination of `noscript` and `meta` tags (IIRC there were some issues in IE6), not to mention that
- this may look suspicious enough for various "web protection" systems that your redirect might be blocked for some users and
- with plugins such as NoScript, some browsers may have JS disabled temporarily or only in part.

Comment: noscript tag is used when page is loaded .am asking page is idle

Comment: @vijay1405: What do you mean, "idle"? Without JS, the page loads, renders - and that's it. No further processing. Done. Complete. Finished.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that JavaScript is client side and PHP is server side. So what you need to do is create some kind of fallback when your scripts (client side) are not execute). Your page still needs to work. That's why you always need to do important (input) validation on the server side.